# Android PreferenceFragment change overscroll color

Tags: android, android-listview, android-overscoll

In Android 5 (Lollipop) the `colorPrimaryDark` is used for the overscroll color in listviews. Now I want to change it everywhere. I found a way to set for a single `ListView`, but the `PreferenceFragment` has no external layout for editing. How can I set the overscroll color for every `ListView` in my whole app?

Answer (score 0):

for your preference fragment,  get a reference to the listview in your `onCreateView(...)` and call [`setOverscrollFooter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setOverscrollFooter(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) and [`setOverscrollHeader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setOverscrollHeader(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))

```
    final ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    lv.setOverscrollFooter(someDrawable);
    lv.setOverscrollHeader(someDrawable);
```

As for everywhere else, and the new colorPrimaryDark to your application styles.